# How to autoplay all video elements on a page/document with javascript (no class or id on videos)

Tags: javascript, jquery

**How to autoplay all video elements on a page/document with javascript (no class or id on videos)**

What I've tried/Can Do/ Can't Do:

1. I'm unable to manually add the loop boolean option to the coding of video elements. I've tried and it won't write.
2. However I am able to add scripting to the body.
3. I've tried taking the [0] out but then it doesn't apply to any video elements

Example: https://jsbin.com/duhejihidi/edit?html,output

(first video plays on loop, second video does not loop)

I was able to get this far by applying the loop to the first video element. But how do I get this script to apply to all the videos that appear in on the page/document. Any help would be appreciate dearly.

```
    var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
if (typeof myVideo.loop == 'boolean') { // loop supported
  myVideo.loop = true;
} else { // loop property not supported
  myVideo.addEventListener('ended', function () {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
  }, false);
}
//...
myVideo.play();
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the solution to your problem may be temporary. Browsers these days are starting to crack down on autoplay.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It's difficult to help without knowing your HTML structure or seeing the current behavior.

Comment: @DennisKats minimum reproduction example: Here's a JS Bin with the code im working with. the Figures auto populate with the videos so that's code that I cannot manipulate. The script can be manipulated. As you can see the first video loops but the second does not 

https://jsbin.com/duhejihidi/edit?html,output

Comment: What do you mean by (1) that you were unable to manually add the loop boolean option to the video elements? Here is a Codepen that shows you can do this purely with multiple video elements purely in HTML. https://codepen.io/denk0403/pen/poOOMrG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get `HTMLCollection` of `video` tag first, then create a looping for iterate all of video to apply autoplay in HTML:

```js
var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
for(let i = 0; i < myVideo.length; i++) {
  if (typeof myVideo[i].loop == 'boolean') { // loop supported
    myVideo[i].loop = true;
  } else { // loop property not supported
    myVideo[i].addEventListener('ended', function () {
      this.currentTime = 0;
      this.play();
    }, false);
  }
}
```

---

Full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 

<figure class="tmblr-full" data-orig-height="1920" data-orig-width="1080" data-npf="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;video&quot;,&quot;provider&quot;:&quot;tumblr&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;https://va.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_rrry4de6F61zhj6kb_720.mp4&quot;,&quot;media&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;https://va.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_rrry4de6F61zhj6kb_720.mp4&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;video/mp4&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:1080,&quot;height&quot;:1920},&quot;poster&quot;:[{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;https://64.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_rrry4de6F61zhj6kb_frame1.jpg&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;image/jpeg&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:1080,&quot;height&quot;:1920}],&quot;filmstrip&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;https://64.media.tumblr.com/previews/tumblr_rrry4de6F61zhj6kb_filmstrip.jpg&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;image/jpeg&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:2000,&quot;height&quot;:357}}"><video controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" poster="https://64.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_rrry4de6F61zhj6kb_frame1.jpg" class="mtz-cfejh"><source src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></figure>


  <figure class="tmblr-full" data-orig-height="1920" data-orig-width="1080" data-npf="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;video&quot;,&quot;provider&quot;:&quot;tumblr&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;https://va.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_rrp2u9YQ2W1zhj6kb_720.mp4&quot;,&quot;media&quot;:{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;https://va.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_rrp2u9YQ2W1zhj6kb_720.mp4&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;video/mp4&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:1080,&quot;height&quot;:1920},&quot;poster&quot;:[{&quot;media_key&quot;:&quot;8e98f738415b076627bad8f17942ae65:bceceaf96e8596b4-22&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;image/jpeg&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:456,&quot;height&quot;:810,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;https://64.media.tumblr.com/8e98f738415b076627bad8f17942ae65/bceceaf96e8596b4-22/s540x810/c5206f85580dfdf768fe67d880bb7a83207194e7.jpg&quot;}]}"><video controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" poster="https://64.media.tumblr.com/8e98f738415b076627bad8f17942ae65/bceceaf96e8596b4-22/s540x810/c5206f85580dfdf768fe67d880bb7a83207194e7.jpg" class="mtz-cfejh"><source src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></figure>
  
 

<p id="demo"></p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
for(let i = 0; i < myVideo.length; i++) {
  if (typeof myVideo[i].loop == 'boolean') { // loop supported
    myVideo[i].loop = true;
  } else { // loop property not supported
    myVideo[i].addEventListener('ended', function () {
      this.currentTime = 0;
      this.play();
    }, false);
  }
}
//...
//myVideo.play();


</script>


</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @Jordy . The solution is dearly appreciated